# How to make a plot in plotly using pandas - value_counts() as one choice in axis

Tags: pandas, plotly

I would like to plot a bar chart in plotly with x-axis being days of the week and y-axis being the count of emails received per weekday.

I have the data in pandas dataframe in this manner:

```
    df_res.Weekday.value_counts()


    Tuesday      331
    Monday       292
    Wednesday    282
    Friday       258
    Thursday     203
    Saturday       4
    Name: Weekday, dtype: int64

    CODE to plot the bar chart
    x = df_pete['Weekday']
    y = df_res[df_res['Volunteer'] == 'pete'].groupby('Volunteer').Weekday.value_counts()

    df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
    df.head()

    data = [
          go.Bar(
              x=df['x'],
              y=df['y'])
           ]

    layout=go.Layout(title="Emails per weekday", xaxis={'title':'Weekday'}, yaxis={'title':'Email count'})
    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    py.iplot(fig)
```

Error message: KeyError: 'Weekday'

PS - I hope the code is indented properly, apologies for any code that isn't.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! In which line does the error occur?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters thank you, the error is at this line - `x = df_pete['Weekday']`

Comment: Looks like your dataframe `df_pete` causes the problem. Can you add it to the question?